# iOS Cocoa Pods - is there a way to import only google geocoding without the entire google maps library?

Tags: swift, xcode, maps, cocoapods

I have a map based app that uses apple maps everywhere except for reverse geocoding, where I use google maps geocoding api. I am not using anything else. Is there a way to import only this pod? With the entire pod 'GoogleMaps', my project now has 230 mb pre-archive. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do it.

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reverse_geocoding) says:

> The Maps SDK for iOS
>   includes a class called the GMSGeocoder class, which includes the
>   reverseGeocodeCoordinate member function which you can use to perform
>   the conversion.

Therefore, you should add the entire pod GoogleMaps, initialize maps with your API key and use geocoding.

You could try [CLGeocoder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clgeocoder), but it has some restrictions. One of them:

> you should not send more than one geocoding request per minute